# Can I serve a multipart http response in Flask?

Tags: python, curl, flask, multipart

I want to do a multipart http response similar to the multipart http requests that forms can produce for file uploads.  It would contain multiple data segments, each with its own content type.  When I google this, all I find is [information on streaming](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/).

I don't care if browsers support this, since it's for a client that is using libcurl.  However, I'm not sure if libcurl supports multipart responses either.  Does it?  Are multipart responses a thing you can do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Building on the other answers, and using the [requests toolbelt](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/requests-toolbelt/) library, the code would look something like the following:

```
from flask import Flask, Response
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/downloads')
def downloads():
    m = MultipartEncoder(
           fields={'field0': 'value', 'field1': 'value',
                   'field2': ('filename', open('file.py', 'rb'), 'text/plain')}
        )
    return Response(m.to_string(), mimetype=m.content_type)
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking at least two different things here. I'm going to answer the one that's in your title: Can Flask send multipart responses? (If you need to know whether/how libcurl supports multipart responses, either try it and see, or ask a separate question.)

Of course it can. Even if there's no Flask extension to automate it (I haven't searched to see whether there is), there's nothing stopping you from, e.g., using the [`email`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html) package in the stdlib to generate the MIME envelope manually, and then serving it up with the appropriate Content-Type.

Comment: @NickRetallack: You can if you want to, but the `email` package can do that for you. For example, if you construct a [`MIMEMultipart`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.mime.html#email.mime.multipart.MIMEMultipart) then call `attach` for each file's part, it'll generate the boundaries automatically.

Comment: I'm wondering how I can return that from Flask, since it will wrap anything in a Response that will already have headers on it.  I guess I'd have to merge the headers in?  Or does it work in some other way?

Comment: @NickRetallack: If you return a `Response`, it doesn't wrap it in a `Response`. That's shown by the very example you linked to. And that example _also_ shows how you can specify the `mimetype` keyword argument to the `Response` constructor to modify the headers it generates, so you don't have to replace everything it does.

Comment: If it's not clear _what_ to pass to `Response`: You can pass it any iterable of strings. A file, a list of strings, a list of one string, a generator that yields complete MIME parts one by one, a generator that alternates yielding MIME headers and boundaries with yielding line by line from a field or chunk by chunk from a gzipped file, …

Answer (score 1):

So, I was looking into something similar today. This is an old question. But so that you dont have search - simple answer is create a Multipart mime entity from email package. And return that. Flask will handle the output correctly.

> responseBody = MIMEMultipart() ...
>
> Response(responseBody.as_string())