# Return multipart/formdata containing png file and markdown as a flask response

Tags: python, flask, multipart

Hi I am trying to return multipart from data from a get request. However I am unable to return a [MultipartEncoder object](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user.html#multipart-form-data-encoder) as a response. I have attempted the solution at
[Can I serve a multipart http response in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643354/can-i-serve-a-multipart-http-response-in-flask)

The below code only returns the 'toPersonEmail' field. How does one return m as a response in Flask?

```
@app.route("/multipart", methods=['GET'])
def send_multipart():
     m = MultipartEncoder(fields={ 'markdown': "> Block quotes are written like so in markdown.",
                                   'toPersonEmail':'d@d.com',
                                   'files': ("pnggrad16rgb.png", open("pnggrad16rgb.png", 'rb'),
                                   'image.png')})

     
     return Response(m.fields, mimetype=m.content_type)
```

Comment: Multipart/form is a mimetype normally used to *send* data to a server, not as a mimetype in a response. You'd have to provide a full response stream (so the data *rendered to bytes*) as there is no special support in Flask to handle that type of response. Why do you need to provide such a response?

Comment: Presumably `MultipartEncoder` is from the [`requests-toolbelt` project](http://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user.html)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for the response. I will be working with such a response in the future, so I wished to set up dummy endpoint, to test before then. Yes, it is from requests-toolbelt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flask has no specific provision for multipart mime responses; multipart/form is a mimetype normally only used in a POST request *to* the server, not in a response from a HTTP server.

If you must return valid multipart mime data, render the body to bytes and set the right headers on a response object; the `(

```
m = MultipartEncoder(fields={ 'markdown': "> Block quotes are written like so in markdown.",
                               'toPersonEmail':'d@d.com',
                               'files': ("pnggrad16rgb.png", open("pnggrad16rgb.png", 'rb'),
                               'image.png')})

return (m.to_string(), {'Content-Type': m.content_type})
```

If you wanted to *stream* the response, you'd have to supply your own generator function that reads from the multipart encoder in chunks:

```
def chunked_reader(f, chunksize=2 ** 20):  # 1Mb chunks
    while True:
        chunk = f.read(chunksize)
        if not chunk:
            return
        yield chunk
```

and use that to wrap your `MultipartEncoder()` instance when [streaming response data](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/streaming/#streaming-contents):

```
# include the Content-Length header, even though we are streaming
return Response(
    chunked_reader(m), content_type=m.content_type,
    headers={'Content-Length': m.len})
```

The `MultipartEncoder()` object supports a `.read()` method just like files do.